# Free computer forensic software for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, forensics

I am looking for a free computer forensics software like [Guidance Encase](https://www2.guidancesoftware.com/products/Pages/encase-forensic/overview.aspx).

The software must

- collect data / capture disk images (> 2 TB)
- open [dd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29)-style files
- process the collected data

  - especially search for deleted and recycled files
  - find files by file name pattern / extension
  - optional: find files by date / size / attributes / ACLs
- be gratis
- run on Windows 7 (x64)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)** should be your candidate:

- **collect data / capture disk images:** Yes (I don't know of a size limit)
- **open dd-style files:** Yes (that's what I used if for often; it analyzes the structure and, when in doubt, asks you for partition types etc.)
- **process the collected data:** Sure (wouldn't make sense otherwise). You can even extract selected information, browse through directories, and more. And yes, this includes recovery of deleted files.

It's a while ago I've used it last, so I'm not sure about how far its search facilities went. But it's one of the most widely used tools in this area.

*TestDisk* is available cross-platform – which includes (explicitly) Windows-7 64bit. A lot of documentation can be found on the linked official page, so you can head there for more details before installing it.

Comment: How to open a DD file on Windows? The [instructions](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_FAQ#How_to_open_the_image.dd_file_.3F) only work for Linux and MacOS. It seems I need 3rd party tools like [OSFMount](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html)

Comment: As I wrote, quite some time ago I last used it. Can *TestDisk* not read the file itself?