# Tool to recover lost folder hierarchy and file names?

Tags: data-recovery

The program I'm looking for has to be for OS X, GNU/Linux (or maybe even Android), as Windows won't even recognize my drive.

I'm trying to recover data from a hard drive, but I'm only getting the files, not the folder hierarchy, file names, file metadata, etc. But I need to recover all that. What kind of tool can I use? I have already tried the app Disk Drill for OS X.

This is the situation:

1. Friend 1 has a 600GB external HDD (FAT 32 formatted) that he has been using with Windows 7.
2. With hundreds of GB of space already used, Friend 1 gave it to Friend 2 who then used it with OS X Snow Leopard. Friend 2 transferred many more gigabytes to the drive. He then ejected and unplugged it.
3. Friend 2 now tells me that when he, a few hours later, again plugged the drive into his SL Mac, it appeared to be totally empty, with all the space in it available. He says that all he could see were some weird folders which he claims had Arabic names. The drive was in his physical possession the whole time, and we know that nobody else had physical access to it. Moreover, the SL Mac was never online. He then gave me the drive and asked me to help him recover the data. apparently  the data of Friend 1 in there was important (Yeah, I know, that guy should have had a second backup.)
4. So, since it was FAT32 formatted, I booted into Windows 8 to have a look at it. But Windows 8 wouldn’t even recognize the drive. The OS didn’t even mention the drive in any way.
5. So I booted into OS X Yosemite. The drive came up, but, just like Friend 2, I found it to be totally empty. Except for the folders `.fseventsd`, `.Spotlight-V100` and `.Trashes`. Also, OS X says only 371 MB is used, while the data is supposed to be hundreds of gigabytes. I could not see the folders spoken off by Friend 2 with supposed Arabic names.
6. I ran an OS X app called [Disk Drill](http://www.cleverfiles.com/) on the drive. In a mode called "Quick Scan", it finds nothing, except for 33 KB in the `Trashes` folder. That folder contains a single, 33 KB file called `journalAttr.3`.

   In a mode called "Deep Scan", it found hundreds of gigabytes of files. But all the file names and folder hierarchy are missing.

File names and folder hierarchy, as well as file metadata, are important. They are a big part of the data. It would be a huge mess without that information.

Which tool can I use to recover filenames, folder hierarchy and file metadata in this situation?

Comment: "*weird folders which he claims had Arabic names*" sounded like a possible malware infection, but Windows not recognizing the drive at all sounds like a hardware failure - maybe the drive is just about broken

Comment: @Xen2050 Yeah, who knows. I was never able to recover everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)** is the tool you probably want to use. It is cross-platform (so you can use it on Linux as well as on Mac OS X). You will need to run it as root, and have it discovering the disk.

If possible, it does recover the folder hierarchy, file names, and/or file metadata. Whether it's possible depends on several things: what file system was used (e.g. with FAT based systems, structure is easier to find than with EXTFS), how much was destroyed, etc.

*TestDisk* will scan the partition table and show you available partitions, which it then can scan for data. It is able to check for deleted files as well as for existing ones, restore data one believed lost. Restored data should of course go to a different disk, so make sure you have enough space available at some place.

Additional details can be found in my answers to

- [Data recovery from deleted operating system](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/16954/185)
- [Free computer forensic software for Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/28157/185)

Comment: I appreciate that TestDisk is open source and free. I actually am using it to restore the whole disk right now. However, does it generally recover the folder hierarchy, file names, and/or file metadata? That is what I specifically asked for in OP. In my case, it doesn't seem to do it. But neither did Disk Drill. Does TestDisk generally recover the folder hierarchy, file names and file metadata?

Comment: If possible, it does. Whether it's possible depends on several things: what file system was used (e.g. with FAT based systems, structure is easier to find than with EXTFS), how much was destroyed, etc.

Comment: Oh, actually, I had been using the program called `photorec`, sorry, my bad.

Comment: That's the companion program, yes – to recover accidentally deleted files. *TestDisk* goes a step deeper and lets you restore partitions. One usually restores an entire partition to an image file, and then can use *PhotoRec* on that to get hold of the files.

Comment: Why wouldn't one just photo rec directly on the physical drive?  If I run test disk first, may that allow photo rec to find the folder hierarchy, etc, in the image?

Comment: I looked at this tutorial, it looks like testdisk can repair the partition. But it doesn't mention anything about exporting a disk image? http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Comment: PhotoRec alone wouldn't find anything if the partition info was broken. Secondly, forensics like to first make a 1:1 copy and then work on that copy (too touch the original as little as possible – evidence, you know). As for TestDisk, I remember for sure that it allowed saving the "current partition" to an image file. The corresponding item is ["Image Creation"](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Image_Creation) (shown at the bottom of the corresponding screen)

Comment: OK..  Anyway,  I went ahead and asked all this in Testdisks's official forum,  as that's where it's the most on topic.

Comment: If the FAT partition is slightly damaged, but more or less ok, Testdisk will work perfectly. Otherwise, you will need to use other commercial tools.

Comment: PhotoRec is the one that scans byte-by-byte looking for files, it doesn't particularly care about the filesystem  *"PhotoRec ignores the file system and goes after the underlying data, so it will still work even if your media's file system has been severely damaged or reformatted"* (https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). It can scan an entire drive if the partitions have been changed/deleted, or only the free space if the partition(s) & filesystem is still intact. But, if PhotoRec didn't find anything, TestDisk may not have a chance either